# Ghost List Posts by Tag in Home

Tags: themes, handlebars.js, blogs, ghost

I'm trying to create a loop that displays posts listed by tag in home page, to be like this:

[Post List by Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm6ID.png)

what I'm currently doing is repeating this for each tag:

```
{{#get "posts" limit="3" filter="tag:meditation"}}
<h1 class="c-category-title">
    Meditation
    <span class="c-category-title__posts">
        <a href="tag/meditation">all posts</a>
    </span>
</h1>
{{> "post-list"}}
{{/get}}
```

I've been trying to make a loop without success. Does anyone has an idea of how could I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The {{get}} is still a beta feature. Have you enabled it?

Go to yourwebsite.com/ghost/settings/labs/ and tick the 'Public API' checkbox.